# How can I add the package directory structure to my jar

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to compile java files dynamically and add them to my jar which can then be executed. I can compile and create the jar OK but the issue is trying to include the directory structure for the package in the jar. My .class files are being placed on the root dir of the jar file but will not run as they need to be in the correct package/directory structure.

So in short, I have:

JAR.jar/classHere.class

and I need:

JAR.jar/io/ironbytes/corkscrew/client/classHere.class

I am using this code to create the jar.

```
package io.ironbytes.corkscrew.models;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarOutputStream;
import java.util.jar.Manifest;
import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;

public class JarFactory {
    public static int BUFFER_SIZE = 10240;

    public void compile() {
        // Compile source file.
        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        compiler.run(null, null, null, "src/io/ironbytes/corkscrew/client/ClientInitiator.java");
        compiler.run(null, null, null, "src/io/ironbytes/corkscrew/client/ScreenViewer.java");
        compiler.run(null, null, null, "src/io/ironbytes/corkscrew/client/EnumCommands.java");
        compiler.run(null, null, null, "src/io/ironbytes/corkscrew/client/ServerDelegate.java");
    }

    public void createJarArchive(File archiveFile, File[] tobeJared) {
        try {
            byte buffer[] = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            // Open archive file
            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(archiveFile);

            Manifest man = new Manifest();
            man.getMainAttributes().putValue( "Manifest-Version", "1.0" );
            man.getMainAttributes().putValue( "Class-Path", "." );
            man.getMainAttributes().putValue( "Main-Class", "ClientInitiator");

            JarOutputStream out = new JarOutputStream(stream, man);

            for (int i = 0; i < tobeJared.length; i++) {
                if (tobeJared[i] == null || !tobeJared[i].exists()
                        || tobeJared[i].isDirectory())
                    continue; // Just in case...
                System.out.println("Adding " + tobeJared[i].getName());

                // Add archive entry
                JarEntry jarAdd = new JarEntry(tobeJared[i].getName());
                jarAdd.setTime(tobeJared[i].lastModified());
                out.putNextEntry(jarAdd);

                // Write file to archive
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(tobeJared[i]);
                while (true) {
                    int nRead = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                    if (nRead <= 0)
                        break;
                    out.write(buffer, 0, nRead);
                }
                in.close();
            }

            out.close();
            stream.close();
            System.out.println("Adding completed OK");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

and I pass in the params as follows:

```
File[] arr = {new File("src/io/ironbytes/corkscrew/client/ClientInitiator.class") 
                            , new File("src/io/ironbytes/corkscrew/client/ClientInitiator$1.class") 
                            , new File("src/io/ironbytes/corkscrew/client/ScreenViewer.class")
                            , new File("src/io/ironbytes/corkscrew/client/EnumCommands.class")
                            , new File("src/io/ironbytes/corkscrew/client/ServerDelegate.class")
                            };

                    JarFactory jar = new JarFactory();
                    jar.compile();
                    jar.createJarArchive(new File("/Users/Bob/Desktop/he.jar"), arr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested in the future, I solved this by using the following code:

```
out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("io/ironbytes/corkscrew/client/ClientInitiator.class"));
```

The `new ZipEntry` class from `import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;` will allow you to include your class and the directory structure in your jar at the same time.